# How to pass a list from R into Fortran

Tags: r, fortran

I am having trouble interfacing R and Fortran. I created a list object in R, and I'm wondering whether I can pass the list from R into Fortran directly without `unlist()`?

For example:

```
a=matrix(1:6,3,2)
b=matrix(1:6,3,2)

A=list(a,b)
```

I cannot use `.Fortran("name", A)` to pass the list into Fortran. Does anyone know how to make it work?

Comment: What would you like your list to correspond to in Fortran? Show details of what you tried.

Comment: According to this page http://astrostatistics.psu.edu/su07/R/html/base/html/Foreign.html passing R list to Fortran may be not supported? (but it may be possible with .C(...)?)

Comment: Thanks for the information. I will change the list into matrix in R and pass the matrix to Fortran.